# BB-коды конвертировать в HTML

Tags: c#, парсер, bbcode

Подскажите пожалуйста как в C# перевести BB коды в HTML и все ли я делаю правильно?
Есть задание, но тесты к сожалению закрыты. Вроде на тестовых вводных данных указанных ниже все совпадает с ожидаемым выводом, но код не проходит все тесты и как сказал к сожалению тесты закрыты.

Вот задание:
При вводе сообщений на форуме можно пользоваться специальными BB-кодами. Чаще всего используются следующие коды: [b] … [/b] – вывести текст, написанный между этими кодами, жирным шрифтом; [i] … [/i] – наклонным; [u] … [/u] – подчеркнутым. Регистр букв не важен. BB-коды не могут содержать пробелы или символы перехода на новую строку. При преобразовании текста сообщения в HTML эти BB-коды заменяются на соответствующие HTML-коды  **и** ,  *и* ,  и . Открывающий BB-код заменяется только в том случае, если далее в тексте есть соответствующий ему закрывающий BB-код и наоборот. Буквы b, i, u в HTML-кодах становятся строчными независимо от регистра букв в BB-кодах. Допускается вложенность одинаковых BB-кодов. Напишите программу, выполняющую преобразование текста сообщения в HTML.
Формат входных данных
Во входном файле от 1 до 100 строк длиной не более 100 символов, содержащих текст сообщения.
Формат выходных данных
В выходной файл вывести входной текст после замены указанных BB-кодов на HTML-коды.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот код, дайте пожалуйста подсказку что не так.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var inputText = "[I]Текст [/b] сообщения, [b]содержащий[/i] [b]BB[/b]-коды[/b]";
        var converter = new BbCodeConverter(inputText);
        var convertedText = converter.ConvertToHtml();
        Console.WriteLine(convertedText);
    }
}

public class BbCodeConverter
{
    private string _text;
    private readonly List<int> _bCloseTags;
    private readonly List<int> _bOpenTags;
    private readonly List<int> _iCloseTags;
    private readonly List<int> _iOpenTags;
    private readonly List<int> _uCloseTags;
    private readonly List<int> _uOpenTags;

    public BbCodeConverter(string text)
    {
        _text = text;
        _bCloseTags = new List<int>();
        _bOpenTags = new List<int>();
        _iCloseTags = new List<int>();
        _iOpenTags = new List<int>();
        _uCloseTags = new List<int>();
        _uOpenTags = new List<int>();
    }

    public string ConvertToHtml()
    {
        FindBbCodeTags();
        NormalizeTagCounts();
        ConvertTagsToHtml();
        return _text;
    }

    private void FindBbCodeTags()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < _text.Length; i++)
        {
            if ((_text[i] == 'i' || _text[i] == 'I') && _text[i - 1] == '[')
            {
                if (_text[i] == 'I')
                    _text = _text.Remove(i, 1).Insert(i, "i");
                _iOpenTags.Add(i);
            }
            else if ((_text[i] == 'b' || _text[i] == 'B') && _text[i - 1] == '[')
            {
                if (_text[i] == 'B')
                    _text = _text.Remove(i, 1).Insert(i, "b");
                _bOpenTags.Add(i);
            }
            else if ((_text[i] == 'u' || _text[i] == 'B') && _text[i - 1] == '[')
            {
                if (_text[i] == 'U')
                    _text = _text.Remove(i, 1).Insert(i, "u");
                _uOpenTags.Add(i);
            }
            else if (_text[i] == '/' && (_text[i + 1] == 'b' || _text[i + 1] == 'B') && _bOpenTags.Count > _bCloseTags.Count)
            {
                if (_text[i + 1] == 'B')
                    _text = _text.Remove(i + 1, 1).Insert(i + 1, "b");
                _bCloseTags.Add(i);
            }
            else if (_text[i] == '/' && (_text[i + 1] == 'i' || _text[i + 1] == 'I') && _iOpenTags.Count > _iCloseTags.Count)
            {
                if (_text[i + 1] == 'I')
                    _text = _text.Remove(i + 1, 1).Insert(i + 1, "i");
                _iCloseTags.Add(i);
            }
            else if (_text[i] == '/' && (_text[i + 1] == 'u' || _text[i + 1] == 'U') && _uOpenTags.Count > _uCloseTags.Count)
            {
                if (_text[i + 1] == 'U')
                    _text = _text.Remove(i + 1, 1).Insert(i + 1, "u");
                _uCloseTags.Add(i);
            }
        }
    }

    private void NormalizeTagCounts()
    {
        if (_bOpenTags.Count != _bCloseTags.Count)
        {
            var difference = Math.Abs(_bCloseTags.Count - _bOpenTags.Count);
            _bOpenTags.RemoveRange(0, difference);
        }

        if (_iOpenTags.Count != _iCloseTags.Count)
        {
            var difference = Math.Abs(_iCloseTags.Count - _iOpenTags.Count);
            _iOpenTags.RemoveRange(0, difference);
        }

        if (_uOpenTags.Count != _uCloseTags.Count)
        {
            var difference = Math.Abs(_uCloseTags.Count - _uOpenTags.Count);
            _uOpenTags.RemoveRange(0, difference);
        }
    }

    private void ConvertTagsToHtml()
    {
        var max = Math.Max(Math.Max(_bOpenTags.Count, _iOpenTags.Count), _uOpenTags.Count);
        for (int i = 0; i < max; i++)
        {
            if (i < _bOpenTags.Count)
            {
                _text = _text.Remove(_bOpenTags[i] - 1, 1).Insert(_bOpenTags[i] - 1, "<");
                _text = _text.Remove(_bOpenTags[i] + 1, 1).Insert(_bOpenTags[i] + 1, ">");
                _text = _text.Remove(_bCloseTags[i] - 1, 1).Insert(_bCloseTags[i] - 1, "<");
                _text = _text.Remove(_bCloseTags[i] + 2, 1).Insert(_bCloseTags[i] + 2, ">");
            }

            if (i < _iOpenTags.Count)
            {
                _text = _text.Remove(_iOpenTags[i] - 1, 1).Insert(_iOpenTags[i] - 1, "<");
                _text = _text.Remove(_iOpenTags[i] + 1, 1).Insert(_iOpenTags[i] + 1, ">");
                _text = _text.Remove(_iCloseTags[i] - 1, 1).Insert(_iCloseTags[i] - 1, "<");
                _text = _text.Remove(_iCloseTags[i] + 2, 1).Insert(_iCloseTags[i] + 2, ">");
            }

            if (i < _uOpenTags.Count)
            {
                _text = _text.Remove(_uOpenTags[i] - 1, 1).Insert(_uOpenTags[i] - 1, "<");
                _text = _text.Remove(_uOpenTags[i] + 1, 1).Insert(_uOpenTags[i] + 1, ">");
                _text = _text.Remove(_uCloseTags[i] - 1, 1).Insert(_uCloseTags[i] - 1, "<");
                _text = _text.Remove(_uCloseTags[i] + 2, 1).Insert(_uCloseTags[i] + 2, ">");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Интересно, почему `[b][b][/b]` это `[b]<b></b>` а не `<b>[b]</b>`, ведь именно так и работает HTML. Вот чисто ради любопытства, создайте `.html` документ, и пропишите в нем `<b>1<b></b>`, если вариант из задания верен, то единица будет обычная, ну а если нет, единица будет жирной, там правда браузер дорисует недостающий закрывающий тег у внутреннего `<b>`, но не суть. это не отменяет того факта, что первый тег не игнорируется. Аналогично кстати и с BBCode, зайдите на любой форум, который их еще поддерживает, и напишите `[b]1[b][/b]`, увидите, что `1` будет жирной. Так может в задаче опечатка?

Comment: Подсказка по синтаксису `_text[i] == 'i' || _text[i] == 'I'` можно заменить на `char.ToLower(_text[i]) == 'i'`, код читабельнее будет, и `_text[i]` можно закешировать с приведением в нужный регистр `char c = char.ToLower(_text[i])` тогда получится `с == 'i'`. То же самое можно вытворять для `i + 1`.

Comment: Подсказка по решению. Есть типовая задача на проверку правильности расстановки 3 типов скобок в строке `[({`. С ходу здесь решения не нашел, но помню, что реализация очень простая с использованием `Stack<T>`.